# signalR asp.net set username and connectionID

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

i am new in signalR(and JQuery :D) ..... i want to set some usernames and map it to connectionId... after checking some samples this is my code.how ever it does not work ..... the page is running without error but the div id="msg" remains unchanged.

for now all i want is to write the list of usernames and connectionids on the client page.

SERVER

```
namespace SERVXZ
{
    class UserConn
    {
        public string Usrname { set; get; }
        public string ConnectionID { set; get; }
    }

    public class XZHUB : Hub
    {
        //public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> MyUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        List<UserConn> ulist = new List<UserConn>();
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            var us = new UserConn();
            us.Usrname = Context.QueryString["username"];
            us.ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId;
            ulist.Add(us);

           // var username = Context.QueryString["username"];
           // MyUsers.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId,username);


            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public void Send()
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(ulist[0]);

        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.aspx.cs" Inherits="SERVXZ.Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="USR" runat="server" Text="UserName"></asp:Label>

            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="SUB" runat="server" OnClick="SUB_Click" Text="Submit" />

            <div id="msg">HERE</div>

            <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

            <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>

            <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {
                    var con = $.connection.XZHUB;
                    $('#msg').text("test");
                    $.connection.hub.qs = { 'username': 'rooz' };

                    con.client.broadcastMessage = function (msg) {
                        var enmsg = $('<dive />').text(msg).html();
                        $('#msg').append('<div>'+enmsg+'</div>');
                    };


                    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                        $('#SUB').click(function () {
                            con.server.send();
                        });
                    });

                });

            </script>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance .......................:)

Comment: Could you open the developer tools in your browser? I bet you're getting some javascript errors

Comment: I also recommend you to add a hub name to your hub, something like `[HubName("XZHUB")]`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Main.aspx:35)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.1.1.js:3570)
    at process (jquery-3.1.1.js:3638)

Comment: this is the error from developer tools...:|

Comment: do you add `/signalr/hubs` as your javascript source?

Comment: Lets try adding `/signalr/hubs` script and the hub name @RouzbehZarandi

Comment: i added /signalr/hubs script as you see in my client(edited one) @kblok

Comment: then may be there is some problem in hub name, can you show us the `$.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies` function from `/signalr/hubs` js page?

Comment: you mean inside jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js file ?...:| i confused  @Mahedi Sabuj

Comment: Check out my answer @MahediSabuj. I tested that locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the hub name. If you don't set the hub name it'll be generated with the name `xZHUB`.

So you could do 2 things:

Use the default name:

```
var con = $.connection.xZHUB;
```

Or change the hub name

```
[HubName("XZHUB")]
public class XZHUB : Hub
```

There are also another things you need to check:

The hubs are not static, so `ulist` will be recreated in each call. You should consider making it static or change that logic.

The "SUB" button will make a post so it won't work. I replaced it with a normal button:

```
<button ID="SUB">Submit</button>
```